# Where to participate in discussions?

Tags: discussion

According to other posts on meta, all discussions with other members should occur in chat. But I noted that the chat room is rarely used. Is it actually checked? Or is it better to ask a question, then answer my own question, and allow others to disagree with this answer along with their reasons to start off an interesting discussion on history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only answer your own question if the answer is to the standards of SE. You should only ask a question if it's objectively answerable by experts. If the question is only to generate discussion and can't be **answered** (as opposed to discussed), it should be asked on chat.

The reason people don't use chat is because of low volume catch-22. Users don't want to go to chat due to nobody talking there.... which means there continues to be nobody talking there. At least that's the best theory I have.

Answer (score 1):

Well...*I* check it. However, the reputation game isn't in play there, are things posted there are ephemeral, so I can see how people would be loathe to post things there.

There used to be a very useful button that showed up after the n-th comment to move the discussion to a chat channel. I haven't seen it since I was moderatorized, so either its gone, or perhaps not available to us mods.